# Interfaces for Player Attributes

Tags: c#, interface

Could interfaces representing each attribute of a player class be appropriate? Are there problems with this?

As attributes are added to the model, so will interfaces resulting in a long declaration.

```
public class Player : INamed, IEnergy, IInventory, IMana, ...
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Energy { get; set; }
    public int Mana { get; set; }
    public Inventory Backpack { get; }
    ...

}
```

Comment: I dont understand. Name, Energy, Mana etc are _properties_ of a player - thus they should be properties inside the class. Why would you create an interface for each one of them?

Comment: No. Properties representing each attribute of a player would be appropriate. If you take a player, does it sound appropriate that a player IS a `Mana` or that a player IS an `Energy`? Would you ever use one of these interfaces alone? Would it give you a programming advantage to do so? If not, your approach == extra noise.

Comment: I think you should read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b5b8ezk%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzwdh01d%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, that would tell me that not all players have a name, energy, etc. For a basic game, all units usually have some sort of name and a series of hit points which denote how much damage can the unit take.

If *all* the units in your game have similar properties but *different* values (maybe a priest can withstand less damage than a soldier, but can move faster since it does not have armor), you could define an interface which specifies the behavior of your units, thus you could have something like so:

```
public interface IBaseUnit 
{
     int HitPoints
     ..
}
```

Then, each specific unit will have their own implementation. That being said, I would presume that the units will act in a similar fashion in most things, thus, it might be more effective to use an abstract class instead of an interface at the top of your hierarchy.

Comment: @DaneshM.: Please provide more information. What properties are shared between the entities and which do not?

Comment: @DaneshM.: I'd presume those which have an inventory will belong to a particular class of units, same applies to those which have mana.

Comment: @DaneshM. Your understanding of a class is wrong. A Player class will have certain properties - thus all Player objects will have these properties as well, since, well - they *are* Player. It's like one will create a class Dog, and then he will want some of them to have an age, and some of them not. It's just false.

Comment: @Eminem: Yeah that is towards what I am trying to guide the OP to.

Comment: @DaneshM. I'm saying that you can't have two Player objects, with different properties. Either all of them, or non. It's very reasonable and logical when you think about it. Create a Player class which has certain properties that all players have (Everyone got a name, mana etc). Then you can create a bunch of Player _objects_ and assign their properties some values. It should be noted that classes usually have methods. i.e a Player class can have an `Attack` method etc.

Comment: @DaneshM. You have to understand the difference between an object and a class. Player is a class. `LionelMessi` is an object of the class Player. `Ronaldo` is another Player object. They are both Player, and both have the same properties, but with different values. They both can have a method `Run`, but they can have a different value for `MaxSpeed` property. If in different games, there are different properties to players, you should create a `PlayerForGameOne` class, `PlayerForGameTwo` class etc.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, what you need is a class hierarchy, not a bunch of interfaces. Instead of building a large pool of "properties" that different characters can have, you'd be more well advised to model some sort of hierarchy with some base abstract classes that concrete units inherit from.

A basic idea:

```
abstract class Character
{
    String name
    int hitpoints;
    IList<Item> inventory;
}

abstract class Spellcaster : Character
{
    int manapoints;
    IList<Spell> knownSpells;
}

class Mage : Spellcaster
{
    // Mage specific stuff
}

class Necromancer : Spellcaster
{
    // Necromancer specific stuff
}
```

And so on. Obviously the classes that you model will depend on what kind of game it is that you are making.